# Ubuntu 19.10 upgrade has destroyed my laptop. Is there any way to recover?

Tags: upgrade, 19.10

I have a Dell XPS15-9560 laptop running Ubuntu 19.04. I did the upgrade to 19.10 and it has left my laptop unusable.

The upgrade at some point left me with a black screen and a solid white cursor in the upper left of the screen. It had been in that state probably for hours. I restarted the laptop and got the Ubuntu splash screen and a wait cursor. I thought it would continue from that state but it's still flashing the wait cursor after 10 hours.

Is there any way to recover from this?

Comment: If How did you perform the release-upgrade?   Were you using GUI or terminal?  Did you initiate it? or accepted an offer?  If i have a problem with upgrade; I forget GUI & login to terminal (ctrl+alt+f4 for example), inspect the sources (do they look correct for new release; ie. all point to *focal*, none to *eoan* or other?  if so `sudo apt update` inspect output, then `sudo apt full-upgrade` until it completes with no upgrades.  When none are found, I then reboot & try and boot in normally (ie. GUI then).\

Comment: I got a popup asking if I wanted to upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Ctrl-Atl-Delete does not reboot, you will have to force reboot by constantly pressing power button (for about 5-7 seconds).

Then you should try to reboot.

Grub menu should appear if you press and hold Shift during loading Grub, if you boot using BIOS. When your system boots using UEFI (default on recent computers), press Esc.

If you get to the menu, you might want to press E to edit it. Move to the end of line beginning with "linux" and remove the "quiet" part. I would suggest you add "nomodeset" near that point. This is a workaround a bug that affects DRM somewhere between linux kernel 5.3.0 and that was fixed in 5.3.8: "Can't calculate constants, dotclock = 0!". nomodeset will make you impossible to change screen resolution however. You can then boot your modified (only for this time) version with Ctrl-X. This spans of "broken for some people" versions of Linux is what you will find in most recent version of Linux, like Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I don't know why any of the linux distros would release a version containing a bug that will leave you with an unusable computer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that 19.10 will not boot on the Dell xps15-9560.  I've done a fresh install of 19.10 from a bootable USB stick and get the same problem.

Ubuntu should pull 19.10 before it causes more destruction.

Comment: Have you filed a bug report over your issues?  so it can be accessed and the issue actually explored. This is a user support site, so issues & opinions on fitness won't be seen by the right people, and are actually off-topic for this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Destruction is reasonable, because you can still reinstall an older version of Ubuntu or a different distro. The issue with 17.10 was more severe: it risked to really brick your PC, to the extent that that image was pulled back for quite a while. You could try with `nomodeset` boot parameter, because it may be an issue with recognizing your graphical card during boot.